# Ordering characters values alphabetically returns numeric values to me in a pickerInput()

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to alphabetically order the values of the `pickerInput()` shown below, but I get the numbers instead of characters even though I have used

```
stringsAsFactors = F
```

in my dataframe.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

df<-structure(list(Year = c(1951, 1951, 1951, 1951, 1951, 1951, 1954, 
                        1954, 1955, 1955), Country = c("Belgium", "France", "Germany", 
                                                       "Italy", "Luxembourg", "Netherlands", "Canada", "Portugal", "France", 
                                                       "Tunisia"), Scope = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 5)), class = c("grouped_df", 
                                                                                                                       "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(
                                                                                                                         Year = c(1951, 1954, 1955), .rows = structure(list(1:6, 7:8, 
                                                                                                                                                                            9:10), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .drop = TRUE))
df<-data.frame(df,stringsAsFactors = F)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Scope Dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    ),
  dashboardBody(
    
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "cou",
      label = "Country", 
      choices = order(unique(df$Country)),
      selected = order(unique(df$Country))[1],
      multiple = F,
      
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: What’s the purpose of `df<-data.frame(df,stringsAsFactors = F)`? Just use `df` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sort()` instead of `order()`

See `?order`

> order returns a permutation which rearranges its first argument into ascending or descending order

versus `?sort`

> Sort (or order) a vector or factor (partially) into ascending or descending order.

i.e. `order()` returns a vector of ordered positions, essentially the index of the order vectored after ordering but not the ordered vector itself. `sort()` returns an ordered vector. However, `sort()` is only for vectors. For reordering dataframes, you'd use

```r
x[order(x)]
```

Replacing `sort()` gives the app below:

[image]

Code:

```r
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

df<-structure(list(Year = c(1951, 1951, 1951, 1951, 1951, 1951, 1954, 
                            1954, 1955, 1955), Country = c("Belgium", "France", "Germany", 
                                                           "Italy", "Luxembourg", "Netherlands", "Canada", "Portugal", "France", 
                                                           "Tunisia"), Scope = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 5)), class = c("grouped_df", 
                                                                                                                           "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(
                                                                                                                             Year = c(1951, 1954, 1955), .rows = structure(list(1:6, 7:8, 
                                                                                                                                                                                9:10), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .drop = TRUE))

df<-data.frame(df,stringsAsFactors = F)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Scope Dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "cou",
      label = "Country", 
      choices = sort(unique(df$Country)),
      selected = sort(unique(df$Country))[1],
      multiple = F,
      
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```